# Нужна ли запятая после слов "в результате"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Нужна ли запятая после слов "в результате" в следующем предложении?

*В результате(,) увеличивалось время на обработку данных.*

Comment: @Лариса1225, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 15):

Запятая не нужна. Это слово не является вводным.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, запятая не нужна

Answer (score 1):

***Запятая не нужна.***